# How to produce MASM format assembly from C code

Tags: c, visual-studio, assembly, masm

I am writing a C program and I would like to compile to assembly, make modifications, and then compile it to an executable using the MASM assembler that's included with MSVS.

I know that MSVS itself allows for assembly output from C programs, but I have found that these outputs seem to add or omit code in such a way that they cannot be assembled by MASM without significant modification.

Is there a way to produce MASM syntax formatted assembly from some  C code that I can assemble with MASM with minimal to none modification?

Comment: I think `-masm=intel` comes pretty close with gcc but some editing is still required.

Comment: MSVC's asm output is in MASM syntax / format.  If you want to copy a function definition or two from it, I think that just works.  Your real question is how to get it to emit useful asm source files that can be lightly hand-modified and actually assembled.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way: when you use MASM you are using a completely different language, which, coincidently, had some overlapping in the assembly code.

You can ask the c compiler to show you the generated assembly, but the feature is not designed to be for cross planting the assembly code: it is just a courtesy to avoid you the hassle to spawn the disassembler, and manually extract the bits you need.

The c compiler is designed to turn your c code, plus the many features you might not even be aware of, into some machine code that does what you ask for. This means that the generated code may include much more stuff (e.g. Helpers) and can be linked to other libraries (e.g. The msvc runtime)  because this is what the msvc compiler has been designed to work.

On the other hand, if you use MASM, the audience is someone who requires to control everything. Thus you no longer benefit for the features and limits of the c language and runtime.

Having said that, if you need to do that, try to focus on using online assembly if you can, as you can still use a higher level language like c or c++ while retaining the ability to mess with assembly code when you need it.

Comment: I think you're making too many excuses for MASM here.  GCC, clang, and ICC have no trouble emitting an AT&T syntax `.s` which you can assemble with a stand-alone assembler to get the same `.o` the compiler would have made directly.  (For GCC, the compiler front-end literally does produce an asm text file as an intermediate step.)  There's no reason why MSVC *couldn't* create a `.asm` that MASM could assemble into a usable `.obj` (which you could link with the same CRT as the compiler would), it just isn't designed to make that easy without manual intervention.